# TFS SDK launch threeway merge

Tags: c#, tfs

There is a class for [ThreeWayMerge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.threewaymerge%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in TFS SDK. There is a function to [Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb138600(v=vs.120).aspx) it. There is a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.threewaymerge.useexternalmergetool(v=vs.120).aspx) to run merge in external tool. But when I run code like this to resolve conflict, nothing is happening. No error. No result. Output temporary file gets deleted. When I would expect tool to be launched like it does with [Difference.VisualDiffItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.difference.visualdiffitems%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Am I wrong in my expectations or doing something wrong?

```
public void Merge(string sourceFile)
    {
        string tempBase = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string tempLatest = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string tempModified = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string tempOutput = Path.GetTempFileName();

        Conflict[] conflicts = workSpace.QueryConflicts(new string[] { sourceFile }, false);
        Conflict cnf = conflicts[0];
        cnf.DownloadBaseFile(tempBase);
        //cnf.DownloadYourFile(tempModified);
        File.Copy(cnf.LocalPath, tempModified,true);
        cnf.DownloadTheirFile(tempLatest);

        int baseCodePage = FileType.Detect(tempBase, null);
        int latestCodePage = FileType.Detect(tempLatest, null);
        int modifiedCodePage = FileType.Detect(tempModified, null);

        ThreeWayMerge threeWayMerge = new ThreeWayMerge();
        threeWayMerge.UseExternalMergeTool = true;
        threeWayMerge.UseExternalAutomergeTool = true;
        threeWayMerge.VersionControlServerGuid = VCS.ServerGuid;
        threeWayMerge.LatestFileName = tempLatest;
        threeWayMerge.LatestFileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(latestCodePage);
        threeWayMerge.ModifiedFileName = tempModified;
        Encoding modifiedEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(modifiedCodePage);
        threeWayMerge.ModifiedFileEncoding = modifiedEncoding;
        threeWayMerge.OriginalFileName = tempBase;
        threeWayMerge.OriginalFileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(baseCodePage);
        threeWayMerge.MergedFileName = tempOutput;
        threeWayMerge.MergedFileEncoding = modifiedEncoding;
        if (threeWayMerge.Run())
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Something");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you  take a look at this open source code  (even using java), if it helps somewhere: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/master/source/com.microsoft.tfs.core/src/com/microsoft/tfs/core/util/diffmerge/ThreeWayMerge.java

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT thanks, I saw it. Hoped I don't need to re-implement all this things.